# Can't find error in Matcher, unclosed character class

Tags: java, regex, error-handling

I'm trying to match a pattern in a String, but i get the unclosed character class, this is my matcher:

```
Matcher d = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$)")
                .matcher(titulos);
```

Any idea where is the error?

Comment: `\\]` is a literal `]`, so you never close any of the `[`s.

Comment: "Any idea where is the error?" [index 43](http://ideone.com/8eKOPL), the end of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `[^"\]` you have to use 4 `\\\\` for the backslash `\` instead of 2 `\\` like this :

```
"\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"|(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(?=,|$)"
```